# Opengl VAO gets overwritten

Tags: c++, opengl, vao

I'm learning opengl and currently I'm struggeling with VAOs.
I would like to draw a cube and a triangle using VAOs but unfortunately, only the object that I create later is drawn. This is what I do in the main loop:

```
void main()
{
  //loading shader, generate window, etc ...

  //generate a cube:
  GLuint cube_vao = generateCube();

  //next, generate a triangle:
  GLuint triangle_vao = generateTriangle();

  glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

  // Clear the screen
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  do
  {
    //draw:
    glBindVertexArray(triangle_vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    glBindVertexArray(cube_vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3);

    glfwPollEvents();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);

  } while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && 
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
}
```

Both, `generateCube()` and `generateTriangle()` do basically the same thing: create the vertices, create vbo, create vao and set the attributes. Then they return the vao id.
This is `generateTriangle()` for example:

```
generateTriangle()
{
  //generate the vertex positions:
  GLfloat triangle_pos[] = //not part of the snippet -> too long

  //generate vbo for the positions:
  GLuint pos_vbo;
  glGenBuffers(1, &pos_vbo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pos_vbo);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle_pos), triangle_pos, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  //next, generate the vertex colors:
  GLfloat triangle_color[] = //not part of the snippet -> too long

  //generate vbo for the colors:
  GLuint col_vbo;
  glGenBuffers(1, &col_vbo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, col_vbo);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangle_color), triangle_color, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

  //generate VAO:
  GLuint vao;
  glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
  glBindVertexArray(vao);

  GLint pos_attrib_id = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "line_pos");
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(pos_attrib_id);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, pos_vbo);
  glVertexAttribPointer(pos_attrib_id, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

  GLint col_attrib_id = glGetAttribLocation(programID, "color");
  glEnableVertexAttribArray(col_attrib_id);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, col_vbo);
  glVertexAttribPointer(col_attrib_id, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

  //function to set the perspective (argument is the model matrix)
  setPerspective(glm::mat4(1.0f));

  return vao;
}
```

With this code, only the cube gets drawn. 
Furthermore, if I comment out the lines: 
`glBindVertexArray(cube_vao);` and `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 12*3);` in the main, the triangle gets drawn but has the color and position of the cube, this is driving me crazy.

I'm using OSX with the shader versions 120 if that helps.

Comment: check the return value of generate* and see if it's a valid VAO

Comment: Additionally, check if the value returned by `glGetAttribLocation` isn't `-1`.

Comment: @legends2k @ratchet freak VAO of triangle: 0, VAO of cube: 0, the glGetAttribLocation return values are positive. If i reverse the order of `drawTriangle()` and `drawCube()`: VAO of cube: 0, VAO of triangle: 1375791943 (could that be -1?).

Comment: There's your problem, the VAOs of both shouldn't be the same. Any rendering calls (or their order) shouldn't change the VAO values.

Comment: Mhm, I see but what should I do to fix this? If I reverse the order of `drawTriangle()` and `drawCube()` I get two different return values - this seems strange. Thanks!

Comment: Put a data breakpoint on those variables and see where they get changed, post assignment from the respective generate* calls.

Comment: From your observations I have to ask: does the cube have the correct colors?

Comment: @legends2k I tried again now and it seems that I made a mistake earlier. The VAOs are different in both cases.

Comment: @Nasser I tried and it has the wrong color... didn't notice that because i set random colors before... oh man

Comment: Could it be the case that my GPU driver does not support VAOs? I read some time ago that the gpu drivers in apple pcs are pretty crappy...

Comment: I've no experience developing on an Apple machine as yet; try some OpenGL extension viewer for Mac and make sure you've VAO support.

Comment: What version/profile are you using for your context creation? You'll need a 3.x context for VAO support.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Thanks so much, that was the solution! I'm so sorry that I didn't include the part where I set the version ... sorry to everyone! Maybe you want write a formal answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAOs were introduced as standard functionality in OpenGL 3.0. On Mac OS, the default context version is 2.1. So you will need to specifically request a 3.x context during setup.

The exact mechanics of getting a 3.x context will depend on the window system interface/toolkit you are using. For example in GLUT, you include the `GLUT_3_2_CORE_PROFILE` flag in the argument to `glInitDisplayMode()`. With Cocoa, you include `NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile, NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core` in the pixel format attributes.

Note that Mac OS only supports the Core Profile for 3.x and later contexts. So you will not be able to use deprecated functionality anymore.